# Filter data object by day Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

The object in question looks like this

```
{{
    schedule['Monday']
    schedule['Tuesday']
    ....
}}
```

I need to:

- get `schedule['{{date | 'EEEE'}}']`
- highlight it in html template
- display something like `{{date | 'EEEE'}} 's schedule is {{schedule['{{date | 'EEEE'}}]}}`

I'm trying to use a loop to create this for days of the week. i.e use `ng-repeat` and filter by current day.

This needs to be done to write different  HTML for current day scenario vs. other days  - example Add a custom class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption that the object will be iterated in particular order (apparently, days of week should) is a mistake here. It will cause problems for both [Angular-specific](http://stephenradford.me/keep-your-objects-order-the-same-in-angularjs/) and [JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_notes) code.

Always stick to arrays when iterating objects:

```
<div ng-repeat="day in days | filter:'Monday'">{{ schedule[day] }}</div>
```

It is preferable to explicitly define

```
$scope.days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday'];
```

rather than

```
$scope.days = Object.keys($scope.schedule);
```

exactly for the reasons stated above.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/EnntuwwDgKIvxWRubTCQ?p=preview

Comment: We don't need to iterate in particular order. The data always comes in order though. I just want a filter to check the current day and then display the schedule for the current day using schedule['Friday'] Instead of saying filter:'Monday' can I check for the current Day

Comment: If it is JSON data, then you can't rely on its order, too. It is not clear what you're asking for. What was 'EEEE' in the original question? You can do `{{ schedule[today] }}` if it is the only day you want.

Comment: I am trying to do this: <div ng-repeat="day in days | filter: today">{{ schedule[day] }}</div>
I want to get an additional class added when {{schedule[day]}} is for today. And not add that for the rest of the days.

Comment: Then there's no need in filter. `<div ng-repeat="day in days"  ng-class="{ highlight_class_name: (day == today) }">{{ schedule[day] }}</div>`

Comment: This is not working for me. schedule[day] is not working as expected. Might I ask for a demo example